# Что означает включение и выключение autocommit в Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

В чем разница в поведении в случаях если я устанавливаю `hibernate.connection.autocommit` `true` или `false`?

И почему включать эту функцию не рекомендуется?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
hibernate.connection.autocommit=true
```

идентично JDBC команде: `Connection.setAutoCommit(true);`

Означает, что каждое SQL выражение рассматривается как отдельная транзакция и после выполнения выражения автоматически закрывается транзакция вызовом `commit()` - то есть подтверждением, что транзакция завершилась.

Это удобно и применяется только для простых операций. Для более сложных операций автокоммит может приводить к катастрофе.

Простой пример: допустим вы делаете перевод денег с одного счета на другой - это 2 операции - списание денег с одного счета и зачисление денег на другой счет. В ситуации с автокоммитом - вы списываете деньги с одного счета и подтверждаете транзакцию, далее зачисляете деньги на второй счет и опять подтверждаете транзакцию - вроде все отлично. Однако, если в момент между снятием денег с одного счета и зачислением денег на второй счет допустим падает коннекшн или рушится сервер, то после восстановления - вы получите что денежки пропали - со счета списались, но никуда не зачислились, а деньги эт всегда серьезно.

В правильной системе вы должны делать так:

1. Начинаем транзакцию
2. Списываем деньги с одного счета
3. Зачисляем деньги на второй счет
4. Подтверждаем успешность транзакции (вызываем `commit()`)

В таком случае, ни падение коннекта, ни обрушение сервера, ни что-то еще другое не сможет привести к фатальным последствиям.

Более подробно, [например здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0))

Comment: а если у меня снятие и начисление денег в одном запросе автокоммит так же может все испортить? Или один запрос может порождать только одну транзакцию?

Comment: @Pavel один запрос - одна транзакция

Comment: @Pavel кроме того, этот функционал (autocommit) действителен не только для HIbernate...

Comment: недавно коллега своим автокоммитом дропнул продакшн базу.